# is there some format plugins work with eslint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

With the help of eslint plugin,we can get a warn in vscode when there are some mistakes in the sourcecode.
But after that,how could I format the code to remove these mistakes?If I just achieve the build-in format command,It will get a result not suitable with eslint's configuration.
So,is there a plugin which can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ESLint highlights code with an error, if you place cursor on the part of code that has red squiggly under it, you should see a light bulb icon show up in the gutter. Clicking that light bulb will give you a menu to autofix this instance of the error, all instances of the errors from this rule, or autofix all fixable rules. You can also assign shortcuts to those actions and call them from keyboard.

[image: Visual Studio Code ESLint auto-fixing]

Comment: It is helpful,thanks! But it is not perfect,I am looking for a plugin which can achieve all this just after a shout-cut. I have found [this one](https://github.com/dai-shi/es-beautifier) but I found it have some bugs,not very mature

Comment: Oh my lady gaga,I have miss something important. with the help of command "fix all auto-fixable problems" in the menu,all problems will be fixed. So,the plugin    I referred is not necessary any more.